# Ext.slider.single is not moving/functioning

Tags: extjs

I want to implement Ext single slider but I have implement , slider render on web page but slider is not moving and not functioning   I am using following code,
`Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 214,
        height: 50,
        minValue: 0,
        hideLabel: true,
        useTips: false,
        maxValue: 100
    });`

Comment: Seems fine to me. Tested in Chrome.latest: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ame

Comment: Maybe your `slider` is loosing focus because of other elements in your app?